# SQL 'case when' vs 'where' efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Which is more efficient:

```sql
Select SUM(case when col2=2 then col1 Else 0 End) From myTable
```

OR

```sql
Select SUM(Col1) From myTable where col2=2
```

Or are they the same speed?

Comment: What have your tests shown you? Those 2 statements are very different though, as first returns every row, while the 2nd filters.

Comment: If, from your application's perspective, the two different result sets being returned here are functionally equivalent, then the WHERE clause version is almost definitely going to be better performing. Especially if there is an index on `col2`. But... apples and oranges... it's a strange question.

Comment: Another technicality I can think of- in the first case col1 must be an integer datatype since there is the else condition = 0 (otherwise you mix datatypes in the same column which is not allowed).  In the second case the datatype of col1 can be anything since col2 is only used as a filter condition.

Comment: @TheImpaler apologies. I edited the queries.

Comment: There is something called "Logical Query Processing Order". The SQL Server analyzes the WHERE clause earlier. If you put a WHERE clause it filters that data in advance and can use an index to optimize the query. In the first case (no where clause) the SQL Server waits until interpreting the SELECT clause to count the result which is not as efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitively the second one should be faster. This is because of the concept of **"Access"**. Access refers to the amount of data that the query needs to retrieve in order to produce the result. It has a big impact on the "operator" the database engine optimizer decides to include in the execution plan.

Safe some exceptions, the first query needs to *access* all the table rows and then compute the result, including rows that don't have anything to do with the case.

The second query only refers to the specific rows needed to compute the result. Therefore, it has the potentiality of being faster. In order for it to be materialized, the presence of indexes is crucial. For example:

```
create index ix1 on myTable (col2);
```

In this case it will only *access* the subset of rows that match the filtering predicate `col2 = 2`.

Answer (score 4):

The second is more efficient:

- It would generally process fewer rows (assuming there are non-"2" values), because rows would be ignored *before* the aggregation function is called.
- It allows the optimizer to take advantage of indexes.
- It allows the optimizer to take advantage of table partitions.

Under some circumstances, they might appear to take the same amount of time, particularly on small tables.

Comment: @ZuzuJH . . . The same ideas apply; I tweaked the answer.