# Proper handling of cyclic cascade/set null functionality on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         NUMERIC(20, 0)               NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    created_by NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL  NULL,
    updated_by NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL  NULL,
    deleted_by NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL  NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_users_created_by 
        FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES users (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_updated_by 
        FOREIGN KEY (updated_by) REFERENCES users (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_deleted_by 
        FOREIGN KEY (deleted_by) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

And I have another one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events
(
    id         NUMERIC(20, 0)                NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
    created_by NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL   NULL,
    updated_by NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL   NULL,
    deleted_by NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL   NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_events_created_by 
        FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES users (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_events_updated_by 
        FOREIGN KEY (updated_by) REFERENCES users (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_events_deleted_by 
        FOREIGN KEY (deleted_by) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

And because of the cyclic reference on `users` table, I cannot have `ON DELETE SET NULL` on my foreign keys. I have instead a trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_delete_users_cascade
ON users
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @DeletedId AS NUMERIC(20, 0);
    SET @DeletedId = (SELECT id FROM DELETED);

    UPDATE users SET created_by = NULL WHERE created_by = @DeletedId;
    UPDATE users SET updated_by = NULL WHERE updated_by = @DeletedId;
    UPDATE users SET deleted_by = NULL WHERE deleted_by = @DeletedId;

    UPDATE events SET created_by = NULL WHERE created_by = @DeletedId;
    UPDATE events SET updated_by = NULL WHERE updated_by = @DeletedId;
    UPDATE events SET deleted_by = NULL WHERE deleted_by = @DeletedId;
    
    DELETE FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM DELETED);
END;
```

Then I thought of something else to decrease the number of queries:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_delete_users_cascade
ON users
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @DeletedId AS NUMERIC(20, 0);
    SET @DeletedId = (SELECT id FROM DELETED);

    UPDATE users
    SET created_by = CASE WHEN created_by = @DeletedId THEN NULL ELSE created_by END,
        updated_by = CASE WHEN updated_by = @DeletedId THEN NULL ELSE updated_by END,
        deleted_by = CASE WHEN deleted_by = @DeletedId THEN NULL ELSE deleted_by END;

    UPDATE events
    SET created_by = CASE WHEN created_by = @DeletedId THEN NULL ELSE created_by END,
        updated_by = CASE WHEN updated_by = @DeletedId THEN NULL ELSE updated_by END,
        deleted_by = CASE WHEN deleted_by = @DeletedId THEN NULL ELSE deleted_by END;

    DELETE FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM DELETED);
END;
```

I have around 20 tables that depend on `users` and included in the trigger. Which one of the two triggers shown is more better for performance and programmatically better / proper way to achieve `SET NULL` functionality?

Comment: Eventually this question seems to boil down to the question the performance of using CASE vs WHERE. I would advise you to take a look at the following question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689364/sql-case-when-vs-where-efficiency

Comment: @RandomUser Also, when I have 20 tables with 3 references to `users` column in each, the question also is about whether reducing the number of queries from 60 to 20 will help.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `DELETE` that causes this trigger to fire deletes 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Deleted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: It's odd - on the one hand, this appears to be attempting to provide some form of audit; on the other hand, audit gets destroyed when users are removed (and also when more than a single update occurs). If you're fine nulling these audit columns at the drop of a hat, what value are they actually providing?

Comment: @marc_s I understand and thank you for the correction. That I can easily achieve by `UPDATE events SET created_by = NULL WHERE created_by IN (SELECT id FROM DELETED);`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Nothing to do with audit purposes. A soft delete functionality for when a reversal is desired to be made. If the entity is deleted by DBA (not through the application) it's gone. Not interested in auditing/reverting it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *neither*.  Both are malformed, because it assumes that you have one only one row in `deleted`.  This is a run-time error waiting to happen.

I would suggest:

```
UPDATE u
    SET created_by = NULL
    FROM users u JOIN
         deleted d
         ON u.created_by = d.id;

UPDATE u
    SET updated_by = NULL
    FROM users u JOIN
         deleted d
         ON u.updated_by = d.id;

UPDATE u
    SET deleted_by = NULL
    FROM users u JOIN
         deleted d
         ON u.deleted_by = d.id;
```

This can take advantage of indexes on the three columns: `users(created_by)`, `users(updated_by)`, and `users(deleted_by)`.

You could phrase this as:

```
UPDATE u
    SET created_by = (CASE WHEN . . . ),
        updated_by = (CASE WHEN . . . ),
        deleted_by = (CASE WHEN . . . )
    FROM users u JOIN
         deleted d
         ON d.id IN (u.created_by, u.updated_by, u.deleted_by)
```

This has the performance advantage that a row with multiple matches is modified only once.  However, if you have individual indexes on each of the three columns in `users`, then I don't think that SQL Server is smart enough to use them.

Now, that said, you have some problems in your data model.  In particular, if a record is updated multiple times, then you lose the information on all but the last update.

I would recommend that you think about a log table instead.  That could have columns such as:

- `table_name`
- `user_id`
- `operation` -- "insert", "update", "delete"
- `datetime`

Then, you won't have to worry about multiple triggers and writing triggers that are just run-time errors waiting to happen.

I would also recommend that you don't cascade the deletes.  Instead, just keep a "soft-delete" flag on the `users` table.  It seems like really bad practice to forget "who" inserted, updated, or deleted a row, just because that user is no longer active.